# How to pass a property name from an object as a parameter in function in javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a following function

```js
self._eventLogger({
          name: 'SeekerCredentialingIntroPageView'
        });
        this.lastBGCRequestStatus(self._eventLogger.name);
```

I am not able to access `name` outside of `self._eventLogger()` function.  `lastBGCRequestStatus()` function accepts one parameter and I want to pass my name variable as a parameter.

I've tried following solutions:

```
this.lastBGCRequestStatus(self._eventLogger.name);

this.lastBGCRequestStatus(self._eventLogger['name']);
```

with no luck.

Can somebody please suggest me any other way to do this?

Comment: `_eventLogger` is a function, so why should you be able to access `name` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
var myName = 'SeekerCredentialingIntroPageView';
self._eventLogger({name: myName});
this.lastBGCRequestStatus(myName);
```

Comment: @T.J.Crowder But then, if you change `myName` later, it will not update the original value, while it will if you keep the entire object

Comment: @AlonEitan: True, but that's more in keeping with the OP's original code anyway.

Answer (score 3):

You could try this:

```
var obj = { name: 'SeekerCredentialingIntroPageView' };
self._eventLogger(obj);
this.lastBGCRequestStatus(obj.name);
```

In the `_eventLogger` you pass an object that you create at this moment. So you can't access it's properties later, since the only who would be informed about the object's reference would be the function you passed a copy of it.

Comment: Guess it took me at least eight seconds to write an explanation before posting. :-)

Comment: I guess my answer needs lesser explanation than yours :)

Comment: Haha :) I just posted the code first and then started writing the explanation :) !

Comment: @Christos: Tsk. Always better to post a complete answer initially.

Comment: @TahaPaksu: No, yours could have used explanation too. But you had a good point about just keeping `name`.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder That's for sure ! Bad habits :(

Answer (score 3):

> I am not able to access 'name' outside of self._eventLogger() function

Well...no, because you're passing an object into it and not keeping a reference to that object, and `name` is a property on that object. Passing an argument into a function doesn't modify the function (unless of course the function's code does that).

If you want to use the object after passing it to the function, keep a reference to it:

```
var event = {
      name: 'SeekerCredentialingIntroPageView'
};
self._eventLogger(event);
this.lastBGCRequestStatus(event.name);
```

---

Side note: As of ES2015 (aka "ES6"), functions have a built-in `name` property. Support remains a bit spotty, but with your original code, you could easily have ended up passing `"_eventLogger"` into `lastBGCRequestStatus`. :-)